# Gstreamer dx9screencapsrc/gdiscreencapsrc change captured area while playing

Tags: c#, screenshot, video-capture, capture, gstreamer

I'm trying to set up one of the above sources to capture the screen on a windows machine. Everything works fine apart from one important detail: I can't change the coordinates of the captured window in either src while pipeline is playing.
I'm currently using C# + Gstreamer-Sharp, yet I'm already considering a native C wrapper.

- Should I be able to change the position of the window using the above plugins while playing?
- If yes, could this be a problem related to Gstreamer-sharp?
- Or does it require a procedure other than simply changing the values of the elements in the pipe?

This is what I do...

```
var pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline();
screenCapSource = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("gdiscreencapsrc", "ScreencapSource") as Gst.Base.PushSrc;
SetCapWindow(0,0,320,240);   //<- works      
//Capsfilter...
//X264 encoder
//udpsink
//link...
//launch pipleline
//working fine...

//When pipeline is playing, this doesn't work.  

//I never change the dimensions, only the position of the window - to no effect.
public void SetCapWindow(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height){
    screenCapSource["x"] = x;
    screenCapSource["y"] = y;
    screenCapSource["width"] = width;
    screenCapSource["height"] = height;
}
```

This issue has been posted before on the Gst mailing list by me and others but no replies.

BTW: A workaround would be using an Appsink to push screencaps into the pipeline from managed code, performance isn't great however.

Comment: textbook first question. Removed your thanks, as per [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)